# Is my recurrence relation right for subset sum?

Tags: dynamic-programming, recurrence, subset-sum

Is this recurrence relation correct for the subset sum problem?
Statement: Print Yes or No depending on whether  there is a subset of the given array **a[ ]** which sums up to a given number **n**.

**dp[i][j]** = true, if 0 to **j** elements in array sum up to **i** and false otherwise.

**dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-a[j]][j], dp[i][j-1])**

Base case values :
**dp[0][0]** = true 
**dp[1...i][0]** = false

Just trying to see if I have the recurrence relation right or not.Thanks for guiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct ( not sure why you used min ). But let **dp[i][j]** store the answer of whether a subset of **arr[0],arr[1],....arr[j]** (here **arr[]** is the array of elements ) can sum upto **i**.
That is **dp[i][j]** is 1 if answer is yes and 0 if answer is no. Ignoring the base cases, the recurrence relation is **dp[i][j]=(dp[i][j-1] | dp[i-arr[j]][j-1])**. To get the exact code and base cases and implementation you can have a look here : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/.

Comment: Oh min was a mistake. I think i understood why dp[i-a[j]][j-1] is right: suppose we have only two elements [1, 4] 
so dp[5][2] = dp[5-4][2-1] = dp[1][1] which means sum of 1 with only one element if that is true then dp[5][2] is also true.

Comment: @newbie_old so did I answer your question or are you not clear  ? If it answered your question you can consider accepting it

Comment: thanks for answering and sorry for not accepting it earlier however just wanted your views on my comments.

Comment: @newbie_old sure. I thought you were not asking a question . Yes in your example dp[5][2] = ( dp[5-4][2-1] | dp[5][1] ) now dp[5][1] is false but dp[1][1] is true and thus dp[5][2] is also true . Hope I answered your query.